# Rails jQuery Form Submit, Wrong Form Gets Executed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, form-submit

I am paginating a list of users, and providing a "Follow" button next to their avatar. I am using jQuery as the means of submitting the "Follow" form.

I am experiencing a bug in which no matter which "Follow" link is clicked, the 'top' most user in the pagination list is followed, rather than the intended user.

I suspect this bug may be related to the forms that get paginated sharing some attribute, possibly related to CSS.

Here is the follow form:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(:followed_id => user.id), :remote => true)  do |f| %>
<div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
<%= link_to "Follow", "#", :onclick=>"$('.new_relationship').submit()" %>
```

Here is the relationship controller 'create' action:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
  current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js { }
    end
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use button_to helper for that. You won't need to deal with forms and js directly. Uh and you get unobtrusive js for free.

`<%= button_to "Follow", :remote => true, :action => "create", :id_to_follow => user.id %>`

if you don't want to use button, use `link_to ..., :method => :post`

Comment: I am actually specifically not using button_to for ascetic/design purposes. Are you sure link_to :method=>:post is workable? Check out this stackflow article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964599/rails-how-do-you-submit-a-form-with-a-text-link

Comment: Well, the purpose of link in HTML is to make a get request, therefore :method => :post seems to be like a bit of hacking against it, on the other hand your approach with onclick is even worse in these terms. link_to works, just try it. And make sure you have routes and actions in your controller set up correctly to accept passed parameters and method.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I think there may be a misunderstanding regarding the nature of the problem. The code works for the entirety of the site, with the exception of when it is applied in the context of pagination. The onclick is the correct approach, as I want to use jQuery/CSS and a toggling image as the "button".

Comment: The problem is that you use jQuery class selector. I assume all of the forms have the same css class, therefore only top one is submitted. 
Secondly, onclick is not considered a good approach, better bind a click event on dom element from your js file.
I still suggest you use my approach and add any js animation and css styling from js and css files using selectors.
If you want to go with your approach, then you whether have to assign unique css id to each form so you can find a right form from your onclick event, or you should use a relative path in your selector, like parent(form) or smth.