# Replace submit button with glyphicon in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, submit, glyphicons

Quick question. I have:

```
<%= f.submit "Like", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
```

and instead of the text reading "like" I would like to replace the whole button with the:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumb-up"></span>
```

symbol.

What would be the correct way in rails to replace the submit button with the thumbs up icon but have it do the same thing?

**UPDATE**

I found this:

```
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary") do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> 
<% end %>
```

But the only problem is that this still shows the button behind the glyphicon (even if I remove btn btn-primary). Does anyone know how to get rid of the button?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604304/rails-and-bootstrap-add-html-tags-to-a-submit-button-text

Comment: I spent a while looking for the answer to this question myself.  Ended up just having to hard code it without form helpers.  Hopefully you'll have better luck.

Comment: The button appearance is coming from your CSS classes "btn btn-primary". You don't need those to make it beahave like a button though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i didn't understand well at first. 
In order to avoid the button, you actually have a couple of ways:

- applying some css to your button so that it becomes transparent, leaving just the icon visible:

  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
- substitute rails submit with jquery (or similar) submit. Something like:

  `<span class="glyphicon"></span>`

  `$('span.glyphicon').click(function(){ $('#my_form').submit()});`

Until rails 3 one could use the link_to_function or link_to_remote helpers to call a js function, but since rails 4 this is not possible anymore.
Take a look also [Rails 3 submit form with link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791538/rails-3-submit-form-with-link), and here [Rails, how do you submit a form with a text link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964599/rails-how-do-you-submit-a-form-with-a-text-link)

hope this helps

Comment: Great thanks for this! I have actually decided to go about it another way but this is great if I want to go back. ill accept the answer for others :)

Answer (score 5):

I found this to work for submitting my form with a button containing only a glyphicon:

`<%= button_tag "", type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right" %>`

glyphicon class is a checkbox instead of thumbs up, and bootstrap btn styling is `default` instead of `primary`, but it should do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can add following class to the button to hide button background,

```
    .like-page{
      background: none;
      border: none;
    }
```